# animation gltf 3d object in three.js

Tags: three.js, gltf

I have a working GLTF object and trying to apply animation without AnimationMixer, but in the end I have an error:Identifier 'cube' has already been declared. Moreover, if I work with an Mesh object, everything is fine. what's happening? Thanks.

```
let cubes, cube;

let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load(
  'model/cubes.glb',

  function ( gltf ) {
  cubes = gltf.scene;
  });

cube = new three.Mesh(cubes);
scene.add(cube);
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();

var lastFrameTime = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
var totalGameTime = 0;
function update(dt, t) {

    setTimeout(function() {
        var currTime = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
        var dt = currTime - (lastFrameTime || currTime);
        totalGameTime += dt;

        update(dt, totalGameTime);

        lastFrameTime = currTime;
    }, 0);
}


function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    requestAnimFrame(render);
}

render();
update(0, totalGameTime);
```

Comment: the error tells, that you've declared the variable `cube` twice (in the same scope). Here (first): `let cubes, cube;` and here (second): `let cube = new three.Mesh(cubes);` Remove `let` here: `cube = new three.Mesh(cubes);`

Comment: thanks, but it didn’t solve my problem. I do not have any error, but the animation does not work either. I have a black screen. I suspect (cube.rotation.y += 0.01;    requestAnimFrame(render);) is not working with GLTFobjects together

Comment: error "Cannot read property 'rotation' of undefined" appears.

Comment: I'm guessing to synchronize `loader.load` whit a part, that depends on the loaded model. Because, loading of `gltf` is asynchronous, and you'll get a model after some time, but that part: `render();` gets executed instantly. Or as an option, you can check if `cube` is not `undefined`, and then rotate it: `if (cube) cube.rotation.x += 0.01`. And this part: `new three.Mesh(cubes);` looks strange. Commonly, it's uppercase `new THREE`, like you're using here: `let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();`

Comment: I tried to applied validation to rotate (if (cube) cube.rotation.x +=0,1), but that didn`t help. I don`t find any example to jobs for animation GLTF object with rotation (without AnimationMixer). If i change gltf object on mesh, then everything works.